# Shorten hex string in node.js

Tags: node.js, string, hex

I have very long hex string `ItdKl7s5WVHZO3hPfuwSa3lod3LsNzg8QaYlVW5mPRwnHt0_zR7QxdKbN6BQkvdgivvKMKuhuUhmJrR1kYoapfwcmWCDy1zEK5dyf3Vk9LzTsRdiPhnqE01Y3d8GvWzEKt54210-MybTvE0qmFkNXC_-qjNmdhil-LSEGqItruRrlTZC1SLvzRxj3iNEZfch96SbJ_8JfQpvDobhepJRB`. Is it possible to shorten it and decode back in node.js?

Comment: That is definitely not hex. Any way, why do you want to shorten it. Is it okay if it contains non-printable characters when it's shortened?

Comment: it's what `cipher.final('hex')` returns. I assume it's a very big hex number.

Comment: That makes no sense. `cipher.final('hex')` returns hex. `hex` only contains 16 distinct symbols (usually `abcdef0123456789`). Your string contains 63 distinct symbols.

Comment: try this code `var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', 'd6F3Efeq');
  var crypted = cipher.update(JSON.stringify(<SOME BIG OBJECT>),'utf8','hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;`

Comment: That correctly outputs hex for me (after I add a random password for the cipher). I get something like `fd8c2be5e2b402dcc4355a2215f538def3ddb71ff22408411e5103...`

Comment: In general you can get shorter output that is still using printable characters by using `'base64` instead of `'hex'` in both places that you have `hex` in your code.

Comment: That's already looks like base64url encoding